# How to check whether a user is logged in or not in Servlets?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, servlets

In a *Java Servlet* I want to check programmatically whether a user is **logged in** or **not**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) as pointed out in the other answer only applies when you make use of Java EE provided container managed security as outlined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html).

If you're however homegrowing your own security, then you need to rely on the [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). It's not that hard, here is an overview what you need to implement on each step:

On login, get the `User` from the DB and store it in session in [servlet's](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) `doPost()`:

```
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);
if (user != null) {
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
} else {
    // Show error like "Login failed, unknown user, try again.".
}
```

On logout, just invalidate the session in servlet's `doPost()`. It will destroy the session and clear out all attributes.

```
session.invalidate();
```

To check if an `User` is logged in or not, create a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which is mapped with an `url-pattern` which covers the restricted pages, e.g. `/secured/*`, `/protected/*`, etcetera and implement `doFilter()` like below:

```
if (session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContectPath() + "/login"); // Not logged in, redirect to login page.
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Logged in, just continue chain.
}
```

That's basically all.

#### See also:

- [How to redirect to Login page when Session is expired in Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026846/how-to-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-is-expired-in-java-web-application/32627461#32627461)
- [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)

Comment: `chain.doFilter(request, response);` what's chain here?

Answer (score 0):

[HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal())

Comment: thanks yes i can work. But tell me how i can set the usename in servlet so that it is further called by getUserPrincipal()

Comment: You can't set the principal in a J2EE app. App server has to that instead.
Your app only has to provide definitions of security rules and its assignments to servlets, app server does the rest (i.e. identifying a user and authorizing them to access particular endpoint.
There are many tutorials regarding J2EE security, e.g. one here: http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Servlet 3.1 Specification](https://java.net/downloads/servlet-spec/Proposed%20Final%20Draft/servlet-3_1-PFD.pdf) (Section 13.10) states:

> Being logged into an application during the processing of a request, corresponds precisely to there being a valid *non*-`null` caller identity associated with the request as may be determined by calling `getRemoteUser` or `getUserPrincipal` on the request. A `null` return value from either of these methods indicates that the caller is not logged into the application with respect to the processing of the request.