# How to transfer session objects among domain

Tags: java

I need to redirect from one domain into an another. Hence I am using sendRedirect(url). But i need to also get few attributes which were set in session. Is there any way to get the session attributes after using sendRedirect(url)?

Comment: cookies , query parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461838/preserving-session-in-java-with-sendredirect

Comment: cookies will not be useful if the user's cookie is disabled. I have a list of attributes set in the session which will be difficult to pass as url parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it's impossible to access one application session from another. If you're redirecting you can pass required attributes in the url (but maybe it's not the best idea, conisder security for this approach). Some servers may have some magic tricks to share sessions between applications deployed on the same server (I think it's possible in weblogic)