# typo3 flow always creates new session

Tags: session, typo3-flow

we have several TYPO3 FLOW projects in development. In all our projects the session handling does not work as expected. We are using FLOW 2.1

On every request, there will be generated a completely new session identifier. There is NO cookie set for identification purposes.

session configuration is the standard configuration from TYPO3:Flow:session: ...

Tested with several browsers, all act the same.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: What is your development domain? Maybe something without a dot, like http://localhost/ ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2139259/693617

Comment: I am developping on a live server with a domain like part.part.subdomain.domain.tld. The session:cookie:domain: is set to the default value NULL, but I already tried to set it to my own domain name.

Comment: How does your code look like? How do you create a session? Can you given an example what you tried? - Could be helpful to answer your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, we found the problem. It was user-made ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who find the question looking for an answer to the same question: We found the solution for the problem:

For fast debugging we had an echo statement in the controller action. That echo started the output to the client and the headers were sent. However, the session cookie would be set **after** the action was finished. Flow would send all needed headers immediately before the actual content.

But at that time the headers were already sent. To prevent the PHP warning and because headers would not be accepted any more anyway, Flow silently did not set the cookie header.

Comment: Hi, could you please accept that answer yourself, just in order to mark this solved. Thanks!