# FilterChain#doFilter does not redirect to desired page

Tags: java, redirect, servlets, authentication, servlet-filters

I have implemented a simple web app with user authentication, and tried to add a filter to redirect to the login page, when the user is not logged in. The filter does the redirection properly, when it is supposed to, but it keeps redirecting to the login page when a user is logged in too.

Is there any specific method to be called, in case there is no need for redirection (besides `filterChain#doFilter`), or is there another mistake in my code?

Here are the classes and pages:

login page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method= "post" action="login" name="Login Form" id="login-form">
    <h2>login</h2>
    <label for="username">username</label><input name="username" type="text" id="username" />
    <br>
    <label for="password">password</label><input name="password" type="password" id="password" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="login" id="submitButton" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

login handler:

```java
package control;

import model.User;
import repository.DAOFactory;
import repository.UserDAO;
import util.PasswordHasher;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "loginHandler", urlPatterns = {"/login"})
public class loginHandler extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{

        UserDAO dao = DAOFactory.getInstance().getUserDAO();
        String username = request.getParameter("username");

        try {
            if(dao.validateUserLogin(username,request.getParameter("password"))>0) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("username",username);
                session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30*60);
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("username",username);
                cookie.setMaxAge(30*60);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
                User user = dao.getUserByUsername(username);
                user.setLastHashedSessionID(PasswordHasher.hashPassword(session.getId(),user.getSalt()));
                dao.updateUser(user);

                response.sendRedirect("page.html");
            }
            else
                request.getRequestDispatcher("error.html").forward(request,response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

authentication filter:

```java
package control;

import model.User;
import repository.DAOFactory;
import repository.UserDAO;
import util.PasswordHasher;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/page.html"})
public class authenticationFilter implements Filter{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            System.out.print("Checking username in session...");
            if(session.getAttribute("username") == null) {
                System.out.println("FAILED!");
                System.out.println("Redirect needed, no username in session!");
                req.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").forward(request, response);
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("OK");
            User user;
            UserDAO dao = DAOFactory.getInstance().getUserDAO();
            String username = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("username").toString();
            user = dao.getUserByUsername(username);
            System.out.print("Checking session ID...");
            if(!user.getLastHashedSessionID().equals(PasswordHasher.hashPassword(session.getId(),user.getSalt()))) {
                System.out.println("FAILED!");
                session.invalidate();
                req.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").forward(request,response);
                System.out.println("Redirect needed, invalid session!");
                return;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("OK");
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("end of doFilter!");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Silly question: Is the second `OK` printed out in your `authenticationFilter` meaning that `chain.doFilter` is reached?

Comment: @Al1 I suppose yes. The console output is the following: `Checking username in session...FAILED!` , `Redirect needed, no username in session!`, then, after a login, `Checking username in session...OK`, `Checking session ID...OK`, `end of doFilter!`.

Comment: I have recreated your project in local and strangely when I'm under http, I have another problem: the username is not found so it keeps redirect me to login page. However, if I'm under https, I can access to `page.html` without any problem. I used [this link for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46393979/4906586). If you have the same behaviour, I'll try to find why and post an answer