# Problem in storing and retrieving arraylist in session

Tags: java, jsp, session, session-variables

I need to show the previously executed command in the table in the webpage for the current session. But, I am getting only one the last executed command in the table. I don't know what I am missing...

```
ArrayList commands = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("commands");
String cmd = (String)request.getAttribute("text1");
commands.add(cmd);
session.setAttribute("commands",commands);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be an explanation error only, but the 4th line should ideally be

session.setAttribute("commands",commands);

Comment: Please add how you are getting the session, also how you are generating the table. This piece of code looks fine to me. May be the session is being reset at some point .. may be .. just trying to think aloud

Comment: I am getting an empty arraylist initially like this, ArrayList commands = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("cmd")==null?new ArrayList():(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("cmd");           I am showing the array list as table using for loop as in the next comment

Comment: int len = commands.size();
      if(len > 0)
      {
       for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
       {
        String stripVal = GridUtil.getStripofValues((String)commands.get(i),30);
        String query = (String)commands.get(i);
%>        <tr><td class="tableRow" ></td></tr>
<%       }
      }

Comment: ArrayList commands = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("cmd")==null?new ArrayList():(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("cmd");    This line has the cmd/commands mismatch, I hope you have already adjusted that. I think the problem is your session is being recreated with every request thts why you are always getting a new ArrayList from this line.

Comment: Yeah. Correct. The session is recreated every time... How to get the older session?

Comment: Where might be the error for session being recreated every time

Comment: Check the options here, there are multiple threads here where this topic was discussed       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138245/session-is-lost-and-created-as-new-in-every-servlet-request