# java session id structure from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, session, servlets

I just wanted to find out how the Java Session Id gets generated. Reason is I want to use this Id as a unique id for session tracking. It would be very easy when I would be able to do so.

Does anybody now a nice like with a description of it?

thx

Comment: 'Reason is I want to use this Id as a unique id for session tracking'. It already does that. 'It would be very easy when I would be able to do so.' Do what?

Answer (score 3):

> Reason is I want to use this Id as a unique id for session tracking. It would be very easy when I would be able to do so.

Bozho already answered the technical part. The functional part as you state, is however not a good approach. If you want to do "session tracking", you basically don't need to do anything special. The servletcontainer alread does the job of session tracking in flavor of `HttpSession`. You just have to store the object of interest in the session by

```
session.setAttribute("somename", someObject);
```

It will be available in the subsequent requests in the same session by

```
SomeObject someObject = (SomeObject) session.getAttribute("somename");
```

You don't need to take over the session tracking job from the servletcontainer.

#### See also:

- [Best option for session management in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700390/best-option-for-session-management-in-java/1701107#1701107)

Comment: thanks for this! I now about session attributes. Have you ever used a unique session generator? Do you mind if you provide me a link?

Comment: No, I haven't. It simply makes no sense. If you actually want some unique ID generator (not session!), have a look at `java.util.UUID`.

Comment: What exactly do you need it for?

Answer (score 1):

If really interested, you can look it up in the Servlet specification. The important point is that it is guarnateed to be unique per a servlet container instance. But if you use two instances, or you restart your container, a session id that have been used before may again be used.

Comment: Ok. That means it does not take the exact time of generation and use this value to genearate the id? This would make the id unique.

Comment: That wouldn't make it unique across multiple users or multiple cluster elements. There is nothing unique about a session identifier except among the currently active sessions. Your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess @katamshut is looking for random string generator. Commons Lang library can help to generate random string using RandomStringUtils class.
Once a string is generated, you can add the same into session object