# Appending jsessionid to the request url received from request header

Tags: servlets

Currently in our application Client application is sending jsessionid in one of the request header.
Now I want to append this jsessionid received in request header to the request url to create a session.

I want to create a same behavior as URL rewriting, where session is automatically created when jsessionid is appended to the request URL.

And also I want to send this updated request url with jsessionid appended to the next filter where I can get session.

For some security reasons we do not want to append jsessionid to the request url ,instead decided to send in request header.

Let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    if ("GET".equals(request.getMethod()) && request.getParameter("JSESSIONID") != null) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURL().append(";JSESSIONID=")
            .append(request.getParameter("JSESSIONID")).toString());
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Also go through this [**might be useful**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700390/best-option-for-session-management-in-java/1701107#1701107)

Comment: thanks for your reply @san krish. But I need to send this updated request to other filter to create session as jsessionid is appended now and do not want to redirect.