# Logout from GoogleDrive api from my own application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, google-drive-api

I have an MVC application which allows you to login from Google using OAuth2.0
Inside the app i am collaborating files from various repositories, one of them is Google Drive.
I want to logout the user only from the GoogleDrive login and not from any other instances open in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a documentation you needed.

[Sign out](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user) a user

You can enable users to sign out of your app without signing out of Google by adding a sign-out button or link to your site. To create a sign-out link, attach a function that calls the [**`GoogleAuth.signOut()`**](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsignout) method to the link's **`onclick`** event.

For further information, you can also refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083824/login-with-google-how-to-log-out).

Comment: This will Signout from all the Google Instances opened in the browser. We want to logout only from my application. Is there any other way like 1. Clearing "app_data" folder contents related to googledrive or 2. revoking the access for that user on Logout button clicked.