# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - Authentication cookie deleted but the user could still login without being redirected to external sign-in

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, google-authentication

Good day! I am currently creating a website which utilises the Google authentication to enable content personalisation. I have no problem with sign-in and retrieving the logged in user's info, but .NET is not signing the user out completely when I call the SignOutAsync() function, as the user could immediately log in when clicking on the Login button again. Once I clear the browser cache, the user will be redirected to the Google sign-in page when clicking on the Login button.

The services configuration at Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        // Configure authentication service
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Google";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
            });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IRecommender, OntologyRecommender>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

The middleware configuration at Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Login action at the UserController.cs:

```
 public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" });
    }
```

Logout action at the UserController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {   
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Cookies");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

I am new to the ASP.NET Core authentication area, so I would appreciate if anyone could just assist me on this matter, thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083824/login-with-google-how-to-log-out

Answer (score 3):

you need to loop thru the application cookies - here is a sample code snippet:

```
if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".MyCookie"] != null)
{
    var siteCookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Where(c => c.Key.StartsWith(".MyCookie"));
    foreach (var cookie in siteCookies)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I looped through the application cookies and deleted them as suggested; however, it seems like the browser is still keeping the cookies that allow the user to immediately sign in without being redirected to the Google sign-in page.

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect user to Google's logout endpoint to logout :

```
 await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
 HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Cookies");
 return Redirect("https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=https://localhost:44310");
```

Replace "https://localhost:44310" with your own website url . After that , when user click login again , user will be redirected to the Google sign-in page .

Answer (score 0):

This is not a .NET issue but rather how Google works. It happens simply because there is only a single account logged into Google Accounts, which gets defaulted by the process. Either log out of your google account from [google accounts](https://myaccount.google.com/) or login with other accounts as well.

Be sure to do this from the browser you're using for development though.