# Servlet authentication using sessions and cookies

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies

I need to implement simple servlet user authentication (in Java Dynamic Web Project) but there are things that confuse me quite a bit.

Firstly, the servlet for some reason creates the cookie `JSESSIONID` although I never ask it to. And moreover, I cannot change its value, if I do `request.addCookie(new Cookie("JSESSIONID", session.getId()))`, it makes something like this:

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=6B5B441038414B4381EDB7470018F90E; JSESSIONID=7890D45DF445635C49BDEB3CADA8AD99; .......
```

so, it duplicates the cookie.

Secondly, I'm not sure where to compare cookie and session's id, and where and how to create session correctly (i.e. `request.getSession(true? / false? / nothing?);`)

I've read some documentation but still need help.

---

I have the servlet `HomeServlet` which shoud redirect user to `authentication` page if the user is not authenticated.

Here's how I do that (`HomeServlet.java`):

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if(request.getSession().getAttribute("user") != null) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("authentication");
        }
    }
```

And I also have `AuthServlet` which serves jsp page with authentication forms and validates users.

`AuthServlet.java`:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String action = request.getParameter("ACTION");

    if ("login".equals(action)) {
        String[] result = doSomeValidations();

        if (result.size() > 0) { // show validation errors
            request.setAttribute("errorLoginMessage", result);
            request.setAttribute("email", email);
            doGet(request, response);
        } else { // authenticate user
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", userObject);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    } else if ("signup".equals(action)) {
        // ...........................          
    } else {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

---

So, could you help me with understanding that? How do I implement user authentication and keep the user logged in throughout the session?

Comment: I'd consider using Spring Security if you can. Rolling your own security solution is usually a bad idea. The JSESSIONID is automatically set by your servlet container.

Comment: @MikePalfrey I use no frameworks for educational purposes, that's why I can't use Spring Security

Comment: @MikePalfrey so, do you happen to know what may be wrong in my code?

Comment: You should not manually fuss with existing cookies at all. That's the responsibility of the servletcontainer itself. Just set/get a session attribute. Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1700390

Comment: @BalusC Could you be more specific please? What should I do to make my user be able to authenticate? If I just get/set session attribute, any user will be able to authenticate with any valid/invalid cookie, if I understand your answer correctly

Comment: *"any invalid cookie"*, this is not true and this is exactly why that just works. Put off your hands from JSESSIONID cookie. It also saves you from a lot of unnecessary and illogical code.

Comment: @BalusC ok, so how I should do user authentication? I've updated the code according to the link you provided

Comment: @BalusC Is it important what object I save using `setAttribite` (I mean, is it ok if it's not the object from dao)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Firstly, the servlet for some reason creates the cookie JSESSIONID
>   although I never ask it to

```
HttpSession jsession = request.getSession();
```

you are requesting a session here and `JSESSIONID` cookie is created by the container in response

> how to create session correctly request.getSession(true? / false? / nothing?);

`request.getSession()` and `request.getSession(true)` are exactly the same they start a new session if needed ,but `request.getSession(false)` means if there is already a session use it but if there isn't don't start one.
How and where you want to start the session is dependent entirely on your requirements

```
 response.addCookie(new Cookie("JSESSIONID", jsession.getId()));
```

you are not suppossed to add a `JSESSIONID` cookie yourself , the container will do it for you .

Also you should create session once in your app , once the `JSESSIONID` cookie is stored in the user's browser(provided cookies are enabled) ,it will be sent along with the request.

> How do I implement user authentication

Highly subjective and depends on requirements , you can read this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncby/index.html

> keep the user logged in throughout the session

Your session cookies will help you with that once the user has been authenticated ,as an example login to facebook and keep your cookies tab open