# How to handle Session In JSF, not managed Bean level?

Tags: jsf

How do I handle Session in JSF at the webpage level? I don't want to check at the managed bean level. Every time I want to check whether the Session is active I use

```
If active ,Redirect . if not , redirect
```

but get

```
invalid page
```

Comment: Use a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

Comment: Thanks... :)   Can I have any example ?

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026846) and [this documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).