# Handle any user interaction with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, user-inactivity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

In a web application that I'm developing, on every page of the application, when nothing happens for a set amount of time, the page should automatically change. I think setting `window.location` will do for the latter part.

However, when it comes to detecting that nothing has happened, I'm a bit stuck. I'd think that binding all keyboard and mouse events to a single handler could do it, but I'm wondering if there is a better way. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: @Bartek my bad, I should have searched better.

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009260/how-can-i-detect-with-javascript-jquery-if-the-user-is-currently-active-on-the-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly) seems to miss the **blur** and **focus** events on the window. The basic approach is as you suggested but I'd take a close look at which events exactly you're binding on.

Comment: Thanks for you noticing this, but those events are irrelant in my case as the application will never lose focus. Of course, you couldn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't running your site on a web server? A web server, such as Tomcat, can check if a session timed out.

In tomcat's web.xml you would add or change a setting:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

In case of a session timeout, you could redirect to another page.

Here is an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1027592/1916258

Comment: The project is written in Java (Servlets and JSP) and deployed on Tomcat. So suppose we have this session timeout, how can you detect it and take action accordingly? I must warn you though, that I will not prefer this solution because it's server dependant.

Comment: I've added an example (link to another question) in my answer.